# Reading a text file in JS not using HttpRequest

Tags: javascript, file

I want to read a text file which is local in my system.I found many examples where most of them are using XMLHttpRequest(),I do not want to use any of the servers like Wamp,Xampp,Apache etc & also I have seen examples which takes i/p(Browse Button) from user,I don't want that also .

I want to hard code the File path and read the file
Please suggest any Example or Links

Comment: Use a file Input.
You can get a binary of your file without server, see FileReader object

Comment: The linked thread does not answer his question at all. Moderators here should stop overdeleting.

Comment: @FLX: I don't want to use File input Here

Comment: OK, I can see 2 ways but never tried : LocalStorage, or requestFileSystem (non standard, seems dirty)